# Set TextView text from PHP query. Everything works PHP end tested on postman but Textview keeps showing as blank

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have included the Android code below. I don’t think there is anything wrong with the PHP and URL as I have tested these by hard-coding the URL and also using Postman. Everything seems to run OK, only the `textview` text is not being set when I click the play button. There are no errors showing in the logcat either.

**Below is the Android code:**

```
public class Play extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView game_id;
    private TextView team_name;
    private TextView category;
    private Button play;
    private TextView question;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);
        game_id = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.playGameID);
        game_id.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("game_id"));
        team_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.playTeamName);
        team_name.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("team_name"));
        category = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.playCategory);
        category.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("category"));
        play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPlay);
        question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvQuestion);

        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                getQuestion();
            }
        });
    }

    private void getQuestion() {

        String url = "http://192.168.0.14/Articulate/getQuestion.php?category="+category.getText().toString() + "&& game_id=" + game_id.getText().toString();
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                showJSON(response);
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(com.example.conn.articulate.Play.this,error.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    private void showJSON(String response){
        String questionRes="";

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray("question");
            JSONObject collegeData = result.getJSONObject(0);
            questionRes = collegeData.getString("question");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        question.setText(questionRes);
    }

}
```

And I’ll include the PHP below although I think this is all OK:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET') {
    //makes it work
    $category = (string)filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'category');
    $game_id = $_GET['game_id'];

    require_once('dbConnect.php');

    $query = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE category = '$category' and NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT  *
        FROM    answered_questions
        WHERE   game_id='.$game_id.'
        )ORDER BY Rand() LIMIT 1";

    $result = (mysqli_query($con, $query));

    $jsonData = array();
    while ($array = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        $jsonData[] = $array;
    }

    $data = array(
        'question' =>
            $jsonData);
    echo json_encode( $data);

    //close the db connection
    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

Comment: add catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();    questionRes="Json error"
    }            in your code and share your result

Comment: i think there is JSONException occurs  it goes to catch block check it.

Comment: Yeah its catching the json error but I dont know why

Comment: Is it worth mentioning that this is the output from php {"question":[["Mount Everest"]]}

Comment: @cmc12345 please add those error in your question

Comment: still no luck this is the logcat 08-21 17:28:54.498 2605-2605/com.example.conn.articulate W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for question
08-21 17:28:54.500 2605-2605/com.example.conn.articulate W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
08-21 17:28:54.500 2605-2605/com.example.conn.articulate W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:584)
08-21 17:28:54.500 2605-2605/com.example.conn.articulate W/System.err:     at com.example.conn.articulate.Play.showJSON(Play.java:124)

Comment: Could you also post the json returned from the server?